# Access savedInstance from other methods

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Is it possible to access `savedInstance` from inside another method, like the `onNavigationItemSelected()`?

I was using [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/fragment-navigation-drawer) tutorial to set up a DrawerLayout activity to show different Fragments. It works, but the issue is that the current Fragment doesn't persist on a configuration change (the drawer, however, maintains which MenuItem was marked active).

Comment: What exactly do you want to access after state is restored?

Comment: you can persist a fragment state (of a fragment not on the back stack) by calling setRetainInstance(true)